# SSIS script to remove date from file name

Tags: c#, sql, vbscript, ssis

I need to create a SSIS script to remove the date from file name. for example file name is: TestFile_122413.CSV  I need to rename it to TestFile.CSV. I don't know how to keep file extension and how to deal with the date changes on file. I receive this file every day. Here is my code:

`public void Main()
        // TODO: Add your code here

```
        const string DIRECTORY_PATH = @"E:\ScriptsTest";

        //const string FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE = "SSS_PROF_010113.CSV";
        const string FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE = "*.CSV";


        if (Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_PATH))
        {
            string[] filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH);

            foreach (string filePath in filePathList)
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    File.Move(filePath, filePath.Replace(FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE, FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE.Substring(0,8)));

                }
            }
        }


    }`
```

Comment: Is the date always a constant length at the end of your filename?  Can you give some context as to what you have tried?  You didn't ask a question, merely stated a need.

Comment: Yes the date is always the same length. What I don't know is how to keep the file extension.

Comment: Yes the date is always the same length. What I don't know is how to keep the file extension. I receive this file daily. here is my code:public void Main()
// TODO: Add your code here
const string DIRECTORY_PATH = @"E:\ScriptsTest";
const string FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE = "SSS_PROF_010113.CSV";
if (Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_PATH))
{string[] filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH);
foreach (string filePath in filePathList)
{if (File.Exists(filePath))
{File.Move(filePath, filePath.Replace(FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE, FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE.Substring(0,9)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. BTW, have you tried using the ForEach task? That may be simpler.

```
public void Main() 
    {
        const string DIRECTORY_PATH = @"C:\temp\";
        const string FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE = "*_??????.CSV";
        int underscoreAt = 0; 

        if (Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_PATH))
        {
            string[] filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH,FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE);

            foreach (string filePath in filePathList)
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    underscoreAt = filePath.LastIndexOf('_');

                    string newName = string.Format ("{0}.CSV", filePath.Substring(0, underscoreAt));
                    File.Move(filePath,newName );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Script work and rename file well when I have one underscore in file name. Now I have a file with two underscores in name, How I keep the first one, I have two files in the same directory, SSS_PROF_122413.CSV and SSS_PROM_122413.CSV, I need to remove file date and keep files like this SSS_PROF.CSV  and SSS_PROM.CSV  Thanks

Comment: Modified the code. Try now. The code now uses LastIndexOf, as opposed to IndexOf

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SSIS [File System Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140185.aspx). It has an operation to rename a file.

[Here is a video on how it works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQHCkPETmoo).

Hope this helps!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it compiles but I haven't run it:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Main()
    {
        const string DIRECTORY_PATH = @"E:\ScriptsTest";
        if (Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_PATH))
        {
            string[] filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH);
            foreach (string filePath in filePathList)
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    // Get the file name
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                    // Get the file extension
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

                    // Get the file name without the date part
                    string fileTitle = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("_"));

                    File.Move(filePath, DIRECTORY_PATH + @"\" + fileTitle + "." + fileExtension);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Script work and rename file well when I have one underscore in file name. Now I have a file with two underscores in name, How I keep the first one, I have two files in the same directory, SSS_PROF_122413.CSV and SSS_PROM_122413.CSV, I need to remove file date and keep files like this SSS_PROF.CSV  and SSS_PROM.CSV  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Instead of using IndexOf("_") you can use fileName.IndexOfAny(new char[]
    { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' })